# How to login to iPhone application through Google,Windows Messenger, Linkedin, Orkut, AOL and My Space

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-2.0

I am workin on an app ,In  which user is facilitated with  login through any social network account (just like stackover facilitated with login through facebook, Google etc )such as Twitter, Facebook, Yahoo, Google, Windows Messenger, Linkedin, Orkut, AOL and My Space.

could you please help me out with some good ideas and suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Go to this link.this might be helpful
   http://getsharekit.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to simply start looking to the developer sites what to do, for example this one is for Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

More specific: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/